# How should i send data to java method from mapping with Odi12c

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

Recently I started working with Odi12c procedures, until now there was only work with mappings. Now, I have a mapping with different tables and joins, and I need to do calculations by columns. For that, I must use a java method, so I have something like this:

```
 public void static List<Map<String, String>> seg( List<Map<String, String>> comp) {
    for (Map<String, String> map : comp) {
        if (total > 0 && min1 != min1_fin) {
            rest = total - min1;
            total-=min1;
            map.replace("min1_fin",rest);
            map.replace("total",total);
        } else {a= true}
        if (a) { //(operation for next column)  
            if (total > 0 && min2 != min2_fin) {
               rest = total - min2; 
        .
        ..
        ...
    }
    return comp;
 }
```

My list:

```
 KEY    TOTAL     MIN1     MIN2   MIN1_FIN   MIN2_FIN
 ------ -------- -------- ------- --------- ----------
 1      35,14   61,85     91,85     0          0
 1      35,14   8,09      58,32     0          0
 2      85,67   6         6         0          0
 2      85,67   67,6      71,47     0          0
```

I have thought about putting everything in a package and my code in a procedure directly or in a jar and calling it (I still don't know how).

But is it possible to do that? How can I send the data to my java method that way and read it when I return?

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it directly in SQL? That would be much simpler from an architecture point of view. And more maintainable. Could you give an example of your source data and the expected result?

Comment: I also think it is much easier to do everything with SQL, but I can't, I must use Java because I must learn to implement it in Odi12c (apart from the procedures) ... so I thought about doing it that way. My data are like the example I published, I have several keys and I use them for subtract per column(Total -min1), if Total is even greater than zero, I subtract same field (min1) in the next row

Answer (score 0):

Using Java to do the transformation is not the best pattern if the result needs to be stored in a database. Doing it in SQL will be much more efficient.

Anyway, if you really want to use Java you can pass data from the Source command to the Target command of any Procedure step or KM step by binding it. Here is the doc about it : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/integrate.1111/e12643/procedures.htm#CHDGDJGB
Make sure to select the "Multi-Connections" checkbox in the definition of the Produre. The data will pass though the execution agent.